# SQL Comparing 2 date values (one of which is stored in a varchar field and might not contain Date data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I need to compare a date value within a where clause i.e. where a certain date is later than another. The problem arising is that the date which I am comparing against is stored in a varchar field. To doubly complicate matters a simple CONVERT will not work as the data stored in this varchar field is not always a date value and can be any old gubbins (this is an existing DB design and cannot be modified unfortunately. Ahh the joys of legacy design/code.)

Here's a rough example of what I currently have:

```
SELECT A.Value, B.Value, B.Value2
FROM Table A
JOIN Table B ON B.Id = A.Id
WHERE A.Value3 = 'Some String'
    AND ISDATE(B.GubbinsField) = 1 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, B.GubbinsField, 120) >= A.DateField
```

Does anyone have a potential solution to this problem of how I can successfully check these values?

Comment: What you are doing is good enough for the given circumstances, what needs to be done for future is change your schema and make that field a datetime field.

Comment: I would if I could! The problem with the above code snippet is that on running I get the following error:

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Then better fix the broken values instead of working around them. They will allways cause errors, no matter how you solve this.

Comment: Yeah that's really not possible. The field is the way it is. It's used to store multiple types of data and I have no say on schema changes. I'm just looking for the best possible workaround because that's my only option!

Comment: SQL2012 has the wonderful `TRY_CONVERT()` function, which makes this problem trivial.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are on the right path all you need to do is to get the column data type same on both sides of the Comparison Operator.

When you do  `CONVERT(DATETIME, B.GubbinsField, 120) >= A.DateField`

basically you are comparing a string value with a datetime value. Sql server will try to convert the String to Datetime value because of its higher presidence.

You need to write your query something like....

```
;WITH CTE 
 AS (
    SELECT A.Value ValueA
         , B.Value ValueB
         , B.Value2
         , A.DateField
         ,B.GubbinsField
    FROM Table A
    JOIN Table B ON B.Id = A.Id
    WHERE A.Value3 = 'Some String'
      AND ISDATE(B.GubbinsField) = 1 
    )
SELECT ValueA, ValueB, Value2
FROM CTE
WHERE CAST(GubbinsField AS DATETIME) >= DateField
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a cte to ensure you are working with only records from table B that have the date in the GubbinsField during the join:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT B.value, B.Value2, B.ID, B.GubbinsField FROM TABLEB B WHERE ISDATE(B.GubbinsField) = 1)
SELECT A.Value, B.Value, B.Value2
FROM Table A
JOIN cte B ON B.Id = A.Id
WHERE A.Value3 = 'Some String'
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, B.GubbinsField, 120) >= A.DateField
```

Comment: Dave: why the second `ISDATE()`? The Inner Join to the CTE should eliminate any records where GubbinsField is not a data.

Comment: You're right, I failed to remove that - I have made the edit.